# Causality on an accumulator system

Tags: discrete-signals, causality

Can anybody explain why is this system not causal.

$$T[x[n]] = \sum_{k=n_0}^{n} x[k]$$

How does it depend from future inputs when $n < n_0$.

If $n < n_0$ then $T[x[n]]$ is zero because of summation properties.

Comment: You are correct about the convention for the sum. Maybe your instructor is using a different definition?

Comment: But why does it depend on the future inputs, for any $n$ the summation goes up to $n$ too. Is there an example that can make it more clear. Thank you.

Comment: From what i've searched if $n_0$ was $-\infty$ it would be causal. But since $n_0$ can be anything and summation when $n < n_0$ is possible resulting in zero, I don't know.

Comment: As you say, normally the range (for example) `5:3` is empty. However, someone may define it as `[5, 4, 3]`, where $n$ is 3, so it'd be looking into the future. It'd be a completely non-standard definition, though, and probably quite useless too.

Comment: BTW, in case it's not clear: this system is causal, following widely accepted conventions for the $\Sigma$ operation.

Comment: So, instead of non-causal it is, in fact, causal even with $n_0$. I took this from an oppenheimer book and it says it is non-causal but it is an old book. thank you.

Comment: [This sample chapter from Oppenheim](https://www.pearsonhighered.com/assets/samplechapter/0/1/3/1/0131988425.pdf) looks at the accumulator from the perspective of linearity, causality, stability, and time-invariance.  And it is linear, causal, and time-invariant. It is not, however, BIBO stable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The system is causal (it doesn't depend on future inputs). What it is not is [BIBO stable.](https://www.pearsonhighered.com/assets/samplechapter/0/1/3/1/0131988425.pdf)

[image: Summation shown to be not stable.]